# How to programmatically segue after successful authentication?

Tags: ios, swift, twitter-digits

I'm making an app using the **Digits** framework for users to login with their phone number. With that being said, I've tried to find a way to segue to my next view ***after*** user authentication by creating embedding a UINavigationController (*into a ViewController*) in my storyboard and adding a button that segues into my next **View**. I realize that this is not the way to segue after *successful authentication*. Please have a look at my code and let me know what you think/suggest:

```
func didTapButton(sender: AnyObject) {
    let digits = Digits.sharedInstance()
    let configuration = DGTAuthenticationConfiguration(accountFields: .DefaultOptionMask)
    configuration.phoneNumber = "+345555555555"
    digits.authenticateWithNavigationViewController(navigationController, configuration: configuration, 
            completionViewController:  completionViewController) 
}
```

Comment: What is `completionViewController` and does it conform to the `DGTCompletionViewController` protocol?

Comment: No idea, got it from here: https://docs.fabric.io/apple/digits/sign-in-with-phone-number.html#using-your-own-button **(see Alternative Navigation Flows)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now I understand the problem more, please try this:

```
import UIKit
import DigitsKit
class LoginViewController: UIViewController {

override func viewDidLoad() {
        let digitsButton = DGTAuthenticateButton(authenticationCompletion: { (session, error) in
             if (session != nil) {
                print("Your Digits User ID is " + session.userID)
                 let map = MapVC()
                self.presentViewController(map, animated: true, completion: nil)
             }
             else {
                print(error.localizedDescription)
            }
        })
        self.view.addSubview(digitsButton)
    }
}
```

Alternatively can use:

```
import UIKit
import DigitsKit
class LoginViewController: UIViewController {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    let digitsButton = DGTAuthenticateButton(authenticationCompletion: { (session, error) in
        if (session != nil) {
            print("Your Digits User ID is " + session.userID)
            self.performSegueWithIdentifier("mapVC", sender: self)
        }
        else {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }
    })
    self.view.addSubview(digitsButton)
}
}
```

I hope this works :)

Comment: Worked out great! Thanks Alex!

Comment: This was my first post, glad it worked :) please up rate it and mark as the answer

Answer (score 0):

I think your code example has been pulled from the example in the Digits documentation (https://docs.fabric.io/apple/digits/sign-in-with-phone-number.html#alternative-navigation-flows). It all looks correct to me, I think you are on the right track.

What Digits let you do is create an account or sign in to an app with a telephone number.

This is the right code for within a navigation controller, when you run the code:

```
func didTapButton(sender: AnyObject) {
let digits = Digits.sharedInstance()
let configuration = DGTAuthenticationConfiguration(accountFields: .DefaultOptionMask)
configuration.phoneNumber = "+345555555555"
digits.authenticateWithNavigationViewController(navigationController, configuration:configuration, completionViewController:completionViewController)
}
```

This will pop a modal over the top of your current view controller. The user will sign up and verify or login, when Digits has authenticated this it will then pop your view controller `completionViewController`.

Regarding the question, in the UINavigationBar add a button and create a UIAction to call the didTapButton function when it is pressed. This will then trigger the authentication you wish.

If you do not want to use with NavigationViewController, use:

```
func didTapButton(sender: AnyObject) {
    let digits = Digits.sharedInstance()
    digits.authenticateWithCompletion { (session, error) in
        // Inspect session/error objects
    }
}
```

And then you will have to handle popping the view controller on successful authentication yourself.

You cannot create your own form to use with digits, it is always a modal that gets popped over the top however you can format it to look like your app.

The `configuration.phoneNumber = "+345555555555"` maybe confusing. This is just an optional pre-filling of a telephone number in the digits form. Digits will recognise the +34 as Spanish and the 5555555555 as the telephone number. If you do not want this remove the line of code, alternatively you can remove the telephone number leaving only the country code and digits will pre-fill the country code only in the form.

You can also get Digits to request the users email address. This is done by changing `let configuration = DGTAuthenticationConfiguration(accountFields: .DefaultOptionMask)` to `let configuration = DGTAuthenticationConfiguration(accountFields: .Email)`

See this page for full examples how to successfully implement: https://fabric.io/kits/ios/digits/features

I hope this helps, feel free to ask any further questions :)

Comment: Thanks for answering my question, I appreciate you taking the time out to do this. Are you saying that there's no way to segue unless I create a place a UIButton in **UINavigationController**? Here's the thing, I'm using the **pre-configured button** to set up *Digits Authentication*, is there not a way to segue programmatically without needing to create my own button in my **Interface Builder**? The pre-configured button works well on its own, I just need to be able to segue after authentication while using that configuration.

Comment: Hi, in this case you will not need another button. The user will click the pre-configured button, complete login/authentication and then when successful it will segue automatically to your next view controller listed in this line of code: `digits.authenticateWithNavigationViewController(navigationController, configuration:configuration, completionViewController:completionViewController)` as completionViewController

Comment: So will I have to name my UIViewController *completionViewController* in that case? I tried that yesterday and it didn't seem to work.

Comment: no, you can name the view controller you want to segue to anything, for example AlexGraceVC. In this case your the line of code will be: `digits.authenticateWithNavigationViewController(navigationController, configuration:configuration, completionViewController:AlexGraceVC)`

Comment: Doesn't seem to work. Check this out: https://twittercommunity.com/t/digit-always-throws-an-error-for-authentication-with-navigation-controller/57184

Comment: Ah, from that link it looks like this could be the specific issue: **Make sure your completionViewController conforms to the DGTCompletionViewController protocol as specified in the header: completionViewController:(UIViewController<DGTCompletionViewController> *)completionViewController.**

Comment: So do I need to put that in the DGTCompletionViewController.h file or no? I'm having trouble understanding how to go about the solution.

Comment: Otherwise have you also given a view in the storyboard the same Storyboard ID. i.e. the view controller being segued must have the Storyboard ID "AlexGraceVC" and the class must be a UIViewController

Comment: Sorry I think that example before your comment is Objective-C not Swift. Swift does not have header files

Comment: Yes, I have. Originally I didn't, but now definitely.

Comment: And it still doesn't work? are you getting any error messages?

Comment: Yeah it says: *Cannot convert value of type 'MapVC.Type' to expected argument type 'UIViewController'*.

Comment: Can you copy and paste the exact code used to call digits and the first 10 lines or so of MapVC please

Comment: ``import UIKit
import DigitsKit

class LoginViewController: UIViewController {
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let authenticateButton = DGTAuthenticateButton(authenticationCompletion: {
            (session: DGTSession!, error: NSError!) in
            // play with Digits session
        })
        authenticateButton.center = self.view.center
        self.view.addSubview(authenticateButton)
    }
}``

Comment: Okay, I will write another answer for you to try